# How to get a JWT token from one server to another in order to validate APIs which is running on different ports in node & express?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have two modules in two different server i.e., User and transaction module.

User module has one Login API which generates the JWT token, Now I want to send that token to transaction module server and verify in order to protect routes.

Please suggest some ways how should I approach this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

with JWT, it has a secret key, u just share this to two modules, and use this.

Comment: right, but jwt.verify accepts two args, token and secret, so how can I share between them when they are in different server

Comment: Store the secret in the config.

Comment: between 2 modules, u put token in header and i module check such as:
const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]

and secret, u store in config file, or env variable such as:
process.env.SECRET_JWT

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to share that secret_key to that "transaction module server" and verify the requests with same secret_key on both servers.

If you don't want to share the secret_key with the other server, then you have to sign the tokens with RSA.

With RSA, there is a concept of Private and Public key.

You sign the key with secret that is private and kept secure on your server and you share the public_key with all other servers, they can use this public_key to verify your signature.

Here's some articles on it -

https://siddharthac6.medium.com/json-web-token-jwt-the-right-way-of-implementing-with-node-js-65b8915d550e

https://dev.to/tayfunakgc/jwt-with-rsa-signature-1jd